# char array initialization and some char string and c difference

Tags: c++

I see some code written like this:

```
char str[256] = {0};
```

or

```
char str[256] = {1};
```

when the former case, I use

```
printf("%s", str);
```

gives nothing,

Does it means give all the str[0] to str[256] all value 1?
when latterthe stdio give a ASCII smile char.

Furthermore, what is the difference between

```
char s[256] = {0};
printf("%c", s[1]);
```

It gives nothing in `stdout`

---

```
char s[256] = {0};
printf("%s", s[1]);
```

it give a (null)

I do not understand because I am a beginner of c char array and c pointers.

Comment: juanchopanza's answer is correct, but a couple other things to mention: the integer value `0` is not the same as the character value `'0'`, which may be what you intended. And `printf("%s", ...)` requires a pointer to the string. In the case where you get "null", you're passing it the value of a character, which is 0 and thus interpreted as a null pointer. If you wanted to print the string starting from the second character (`s[1]`), you should use the address of the character (`printf("%s", &s[1])`)

Answer (score 2):

This initializes all 256 chars to `0`:

```
char str[256] = {0};
```

This one initializes the first one to `1`, and all the rest to `0`:

```
char str[256] = {1};
```

Concerning the behaviour of `printf`, `"%c"` expects a single `char`. You pass it `0`, which is `NUL` (the character string termination) so it prints nothing. `"%s"` expects a `char*` with the first character in a nul-terminated character string. You pass it a single `char` with value `0`, which it interprets as a null pointer.